# coremltools GPU usage with mlpackage on macOS, very slow inference/prediction

Tags: python, macos, yolo, coremltools, yolov8

for a project, i converted a Yolov8 segmentation .pt model to .mlpackage, so that i can run it. everything runs fine, items of interests are detected on the video, but inference speed is the problem. it takes like 280 ms per item, extremely slow. i run the same unconverted model as .pt on colab or on my laptop, takes only a few ms.

i set the model.compute_unit to ALL or CPU_and_GPU, or any other options, still no GPU is used (you can check from the terminal output, GPU is not active). here is the code:

```
import coremltools as ct
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import time
import os

def is_gpu_active():
    # Run the ioreg command and parse the output
    result = os.popen('ioreg -l | grep "performanceState"').read()
    return "performanceState\" = 2" in result

def letterbox_image(image, size):
    """Resize image with unchanged aspect ratio using padding."""
    ih, iw = image.shape[:2]
    w, h = size

    # Compute scale
    scale = min(w/iw, h/ih)
    nw = int(iw * scale)
    nh = int(ih * scale)

    # Resize the image using the computed scale
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (nw, nh))

    # Compute padding values
    top = (h - nh) // 2
    bottom = h - nh - top
    left = (w - nw) // 2
    right = w - nw - left

    # Add padding to make the image square
    image_padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image_resized, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])
    return image_padded

# Load the Core ML model
model = ct.models.MLModel('vhssegmentation.mlpackage')

# Set the preferred device
model.compute_units = ct.ComputeUnit.ALL#

# Open the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('VID_20230927_202037.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():
    print("----")
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if not ret:
        break

    # Time the letterboxing operation
    start_time = time.time()
    frame = letterbox_image(frame, (640, 640))
    print(f"Letterboxing Time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")
    
    # Time the conversion to PIL Image
    start_time = time.time()
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame)
    print(f"Conversion to PIL Image Time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")

    # Time the prediction step
    start_time = time.time()
    output = model.predict({'image': pil_image})
    print(f"Prediction Time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")

    # Time the post-processing step
    start_time = time.time()
    predictions = output['var_1279']
    mask = np.any(predictions[0, 4:7, :] > 0.5, axis=0)
    filtered_predictions = predictions[0, :, mask]
    for row in filtered_predictions:
        x, y, w, h = row[:4]
        x1 = int(x - w / 2)
        y1 = int(y - h / 2)
        x2 = int(x + w / 2)
        y2 = int(y + h / 2)
        classes = ['class0', 'class1', 'class2']
        detected_class = classes[np.argmax(row[4:7])]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, detected_class, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    print(f"Post-Processing Time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")

    # Display the processed frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if is_gpu_active():
        print("GPU is active")
    else:
        print("GPU is not active")    


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and here is the sample view from remote Mac i use. and it does the yolo style detection
[image]

and here are the sample times, from the terminal output. as you can see prediction/inference too slow:

```
Letterboxing Time: 0.0009 seconds
Conversion to PIL Image Time: 0.0006 seconds
Prediction Time: 0.2791 seconds
Post-Processing Time: 0.0013 seconds
GPU is not active

Letterboxing Time: 0.0010 seconds
Conversion to PIL Image Time: 0.0006 seconds
Prediction Time: 0.2839 seconds
Post-Processing Time: 0.0015 seconds
GPU is not active


Letterboxing Time: 0.0009 seconds
Conversion to PIL Image Time: 0.0006 seconds
Prediction Time: 0.2821 seconds
Post-Processing Time: 0.0010 seconds
GPU is not active
```

Edit: Adding the model specs, and some hardware information as asked
model.get_spec().description.metadata info

```
shortDescription: "Ultralytics YOLOv8m-seg model trained on /content/dataset.yaml"
versionString: "8.0.153"
author: "Ultralytics"
license: "AGPL-3.0 https://ultralytics.com/license"
userDefined {
  key: "batch"
  value: "1"
}
userDefined {
  key: "com.github.apple.coremltools.source"
  value: "torch==2.0.1+cu118"
}
userDefined {
  key: "com.github.apple.coremltools.version"
  value: "7.0b1"
}
userDefined {
  key: "date"
  value: "2023-08-13T15:19:08.788039"
}
userDefined {
  key: "imgsz"
  value: "[640, 640]"
}
userDefined {
  key: "names"
  value: "{0: \'topvhs\', 1: \'frontvhs\', 2: \'sidevhs\'}"
}
userDefined {
  key: "stride"
  value: "32"
}
userDefined {
  key: "task"
  value: "segment"
}
```

some platform and os info

```
Darwin
('10.16', ('', '', ''), 'x86_64')
posix.uname_result(sysname='Darwin', nodename='perceptundrymbp.home', release='22.6.0', version='Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Fri Sep 15 13:39:52 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3.700.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64', machine='x86_64')
```

subprocess.check_output("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType", shell=True) information about the GPU on the mac

```
Graphics/Displays:

    Intel HD Graphics 630:

      Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 630
      Type: GPU
      Bus: Built-In
      VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
      Vendor: Intel
      Device ID: 0x591b
      Revision ID: 0x0004
      Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
      gMux Version: 4.0.29 [3.2.8]
      Metal Support: Metal 3
      Displays:
        Color LCD:
          Display Type: Built-In Retina LCD
          Resolution: 2880 x 1800 Retina
          Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Automatically Adjust Brightness: Yes
          Connection Type: Internal

    Radeon Pro 555:

      Chipset Model: Radeon Pro 555
      Type: GPU
      Bus: PCIe
      PCIe Lane Width: x8
      VRAM (Total): 2 GB
      Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
      Device ID: 0x67ef
      Revision ID: 0x00c7
      ROM Revision: 113-C980AJ-927
      VBIOS Version: 113-C9801AP-A02
      EFI Driver Version: 01.A0.927
      Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
      gMux Version: 4.0.29 [3.2.8]
      Metal Support: Metal 3
```

some more info about the remote mac i'm working with

[image]

some activity monitor while the python code is running

[image]

[image]

Adding more detailed GPU usage, as tadman suggested, with the gpu usage plots
[image]

Comment: What is with the bizarre capitalization "MaC"?

Comment: Machintos computer? i'm very new to MacOS, what ever people call it

Comment: The hardware is "Mac", the software is "macOS", though you'll see "MacOS" used historically. "MaC" with a capital C is something that makes case-sensitive programmers break out in a rash.

Comment: Does the `coremltools` package allow you to report on what hardware it's detected? Have you observed GPU utilization using Activity Monitor?

Comment: the macOS remote is not easily accessible for me all the time, hence sorry for the delay. 

coremltools don't report the hardware info, but i have added some information about the model working with and the Mac/macOS. and also i have checked the Activity Monitor, adding as 2 screenshots.

Comment: There's a GPU usage chart, ⌘4 in Activity Monitor, which shows usage over time. If this isn't going up to something meaningful, ideally 100% when doing heavy processing, your code is likely not using the GPU at all.

Comment: ty @tadman for your help. i have added the GPU usage plot screenshot at bottom. seems like it is not using GPU at all, as guessed initially.

Comment: I've noticed some Python packages on macOS require additional dependencies and sometimes some additional initialization code to get the underlying library to use the GPU. It's worth checking that you've got all those pieces in place, as if you're not seeing GPU activity then you're likely missing something here. Additionally, make sure your specific hardware is supported.

Comment: One observation is that you're using an Intel-based Mac. I might be wrong, but a lot of the packages might be expecting an ARM-based machine (M1, M2, etc.) where the GPU is significantly more powerful and has a lot more VRAM. Your hardware specs there list an embedded Intel graphics and a 2GB Radeon, which might not be supported as you expect. Anecdotally, my 2018 Intel Mac Mini has no Tensorflow GPU support, but a basic M1 Mini does, and the performance difference is pretty significant.

Comment: hi tadman, sorry for the late reply. i bought a new M1 Mac instead of connecting remote, and tried a very similar code on that one. fps went up to 200-300 range. which is quite good. i think your point on the hardware was totally correct. could you please write a brief answer, so i can mark it as correct?

Comment: Maybe you could summarize your findings in a self-answer, as you put in the work here to test.